# IIS DefaultAppPool is being auto...disabled due to...failures

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

I'm running windows 2003 server std sp2 on a server with 280gb hd and 4 gigs of ram.   I'm getting the error:

Application 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

In the event manager, there is also the error: 
"The application specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {A9E69610-B80D-11D0-00A0C922E} to user SERVER01\IWAM_SERVER01 SID {S-1-5-21-146063245-722240192-2763154-1002}.  This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administratrive tool. "

When i try to run http://localhost/ in the browser i get a "Service Unavailable"

any ideas what might be causing this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A web application is crashing (repeatedly), so IIS is disabling it.

What's running in your default web site?

Comment: its a server app running which uses asp.net stuff.  Do you know a way to diagnose what is causing the crash?

Comment: You should configure IIS to display full error messages instead of the standard "500", so you could see the actual exception which caused the application crash.
And be sure to restart the application pool (or the whole IIS), or you will keep seeing "service unavailable".

Answer (score 1):

I would check the user that you have configured for the application pool. It looks like the user might be SERVER01\IWAM_SERVER01 which may not have the correct permissions. Try setting the user to be the Network Service (or Local System) account.

Comment: i changed the user to the local administrator and it still has issues..  is there a log or diagnostic of some kind i can look at to better determine what's crashing ?

Comment: Check the IIS logs. They are usually in C:\Windows\System32\Logfiles. There is one folder for each website on the server. The log for this site may give you a better error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one application on the application pool, separate them so you will know what application is failing.

Some standard question:

- Did it run before?
- When was the last time it run properly?
- What have changed since then?

The error is quit strait forward. The fix is not that easy.

Your asp site is using some com server component. And the security on those thing is, well, nightmare. run the DCOMCnfg utility. Go to Component services => Computers => My computer => COM+ applications

Then go to view=> status menu.

And then try to find the application with the corresponding sid. Right click it and go to properties and then to the security tab and have fun.

If This is a security sensitive server, than don't do any of the above. You will have to find someone who understands that piece of black magic.